# Is it possible to Turn this recursive haskell function into a map call?

Tags: haskell, recursion

This is my code:

```hs
type HoraAtendimento = (String, Int, Int)

htmlHAtendimento :: [HoraAtendimento] -> Html
htmlHAtendimento [] = toHtml ""
htmlHAtendimento ((da,hia,hfa):[]) = toHtml da +++ "feira "
                                     +++
                                     show hia +++ "h - " +++ show hfa +++ "h"
htmlHAtendimento ((da,hia,hfa):r) = toHtml da +++ "feira "
                                    +++
                                    show hia +++ "h - " +++ show hfa +++ "h, "
                                    +++
                                    htmlHAtendimento r
```

I'm looking for a way to use the map function and get rid of this recursive function. Is that possible and if so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look at the type of `map`. It is `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`. That doesn't look like your type, which is [a] -> b. That's not a map, that's a fold.

The higher-order function you want to look at is `foldr`. See [Hoogle](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3Afoldr).

Something like...

```
htmlHAtendimento :: [HoraAtendimento] -> Html
htmlHAtendimento [] = toHtml ""
htmlHAtendimento l = foldr1 (+++) $ intersperse ", " $ map f l
  where f (da, hia, hfa) = toHtml da
                           +++ "feira "
                           +++ show hia
                           +++ "h - "
                           +++ show hfa
                           +++ "h"
```

I don't know if that's correct, but that's in the right direction.

Comment: That's one function that I find very confusing and I could never learn it... Could you give me an example with my code? I have a bunch of similar functions and if I could just see one example, I'll probably manage the others...

Comment: Actually since the list is nonempty you're better off with foldl1 or foldr1.  Example below. ---NR

Comment: You will want to learn to use folds, since they are an extremely useful abstraction. Practice rewriting some simple recursions into folds. Look at the source code for foldr and foldl.

Comment: Ah yes, the old late edit does the trick.  'intersperse' considered necessary, indeed.  Well done!

Answer (score 2):

You want to fold over a nonempty list.  This code might do the trick:

```
type HoraAtendimento = (String, Int, Int)

htmlHAtendimento :: [HoraAtendimento] -> Html
htmlHAtendimento [] = toHtml ""
htmlHAtendimento l = foldl1 (+++) $ map convert l
  where convert (da,hia,hfa) = toHtml da +++ "feira " +++
                               show hia +++ "h - " +++ show hfa +++ "h"
```

Comment: That doesn't handle the ", " mess.